# LaTeX abntex package, twoside putting the page number on the wrong side of the page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, double-sided

I'm finishing writing my thesis, and to save paper I'm trying to use the twoside option for the package abntex. The problem is that the number is in the wrong side of the page! How can I put it on the other side?

Here's a my header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,normaltoc,twoside,openright]{abnt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[portuguese,brazil,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabela-simbolos}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[num,abnt-etal-list=0,abnt-etal-text=it,abnt-   emphasize=it,recuo=0.0cm,bibjustif,abnt-last-names=abnt]{abntcite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[format=hang,font={footnotesize,singlespacing},labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash] {caption}

\onehalfspacing  

\begin{document}

\include{folha_rosto}
\include{resumos}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\include{introducao}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`fancyhdr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). You can then override the footer using `\fancyfoot{}\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}\pagestyle{fancy}` in your document preamble, which should put the page number on the outer side.

Comment: Are you sure the page-numbers are on the wrong side? If I understand right, they should be at the outer page margin, i.e. right on odd pages and left on even ones. Maybe you are simple binding the book on the wrong side? (Also, the middle margin should be about as large as each of the outer ones.)

Comment: IMHO in theory there's nothing wrong with your code neither with the `abnt` class. The `twoside` option, though it's available as a class option, seems not to be `abnt`-compliant – the documentation clearly says so – so you should not consider it when generating the final version of your thesis. If you really want to use `twoside` and "fix" the position of page numbers, the documentation suggests using the `fancyhdr` package, by adding `header` as class option and redefining both `plainheader` and `header` styles. Then @Werner's code is the way to go. Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: On a funny note, ABNT is not environmentally friendly. Ouch. `:P`

Comment: @Werner Although egreg has answered this question, I think your comment (perhaps plus some of Paulo's) is the way to go. Please turn it into an answer.

Comment: As Cereda and others said, the numbers are not wrong, you should just *print* it on two sides, without specifying the twoside option, which would, in theory, also change margins. Check with your university first, if you want to print your thesis on both sides. Besides, you don’t need \usepackage[portuguese,brazil,brazilian]{babel}, just “brazil” will do just fine. Again, as Cereda said, and the ABNTex manual repeats (they even say “don’t use this class unless you really have to”), the problem is not with the class per se, but with ABNT (and academic institutions).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what the problem is. With the `twoside` class option, margins are swapped on odd and even pages so that they agree on the two sides of a sheet.

Since it's impossible (well, quite difficult) to print a `twoside` formatted document as if it were `oneside` formatted because of the margin swapping, it's not a problem if page numbers are on the "wrong" side.

**Step 1**: prepare your thesis with the `twoside` option active; printouts will have the numbers on the "wrong" side, but the document can be printed on both sides of the paper as it should, so you can save paper and have correct margins.

**Step 2**: when your thesis is finished, just delete the `twoside` option, recompile and all will be good for onesided printing.